# Linear independence of an equivalence classes

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $W \subset V$ be a subspace of a vector space $V$. $u_{1}, u_{2}, \ldots u_{n} \in V$. Let's consider a quotient group $V/W$ and its elements $u^{'}_{i}=u_{i}+W$. Assume that $u_{1}, u_{2}, \ldots u_{n}$ are linear independent, does it imply that $u^{'}_{1}, u^{'}_{2}, \ldots u^{'}_{n}$ are also linear independent and vice versa?

If  $u_{1}, u_{2}, \ldots u_{n}$ are linear independent, then $\alpha_{1}u_{1}+\ldots \alpha_{n} u_{n} \neq 0$ for a non-zero tuples $(\alpha_{1}, \alpha_{2}, \ldots, \alpha_{n})$. $u_{i}=u^{'}_{i}-W$, then the condition of $u_{1}, u_{2}, \ldots u_{n}$ independence is equivalent to the $\alpha_{1} u^{'}_{1}+\alpha_{2}u^{'}_{2}+\ldots \alpha_{n}u^{'}_{n} \neq W(\alpha_{1}+\alpha_{2}+\ldots +\alpha_{n}), \forall w \in W$. We can choose $w_{0}=0$ and get that $\alpha_{1} u^{'}_{1}+\alpha_{2}u^{'}_{2}+\ldots \alpha_{n}u^{'}_{n} \neq 0$, so the first statement is correct.

My solution might be wrong, though i believe that it should works. )

Could somebody give me a hint or find a bad place in my proof?

Answer (score 0):

If you take, for example, a basis of $W$, its elements are l.i, but their classes are zero.